# How to Thumb Preview in Picture Box From Thumb Impression Device

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to preview an image in picture box from Thumb Impression device. I am doing this successfully on button click which shows an image of my thumb on button click. But my requirement is, when i keep my thumb it should immediately shows my thumb without button click. Following is the code which i am using in button click. Please anyone guide.

```
   private void GetMinDataBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SGFingerPrintManager manager = new SGFingerPrintManager();
            int deviceInfo = manager.Init(SGFPMDeviceName.DEV_AUTO);
            deviceInfo = manager.OpenDevice(0);
            try
            {
                this.m_TestMin.Initialize();
                SGFPMDeviceInfoParam pInfo = new SGFPMDeviceInfoParam();
                deviceInfo = manager.GetDeviceInfo(pInfo);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[pInfo.ImageWidth * pInfo.ImageHeight]; //Here sometime it fails to load image through device. And sometimes it continously works without an issue. 
                deviceInfo = manager.GetImageEx(buffer, 0x1388, (int)this.FDxPicBox.Handle, 50);
                if (manager.CreateTemplate(buffer, this.m_TestMin) == 0)
                {
                    this.FdxToFIRBtn.Enabled = true;
                    this.VerifyBtn.Enabled = true;
                    this.StatusBar.Text = "Get Minutiae Data Success";
                    deviceInfo = manager.CloseDevice();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                deviceInfo = manager.CloseDevice();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                this.StatusBar.Text = "Thumb data failed to get";
            }

        }
```

Comment: You'll probably need a thread which waits for input from the device, or polls the device on intervals to see if there is data to handle. I don't know enough about the fingerprint device manager to know what kind of functionality it offers in that aspect though.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?